# Node - What are the other application frameworks like Express that run on Node ?

Tags: node.js

I have been looking into node and trying to understand the various components . I have tried node express . Are there other application frameworks like express ? Is there any one framework recommended ?

Comment: Koa is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many frameworks and libraries that you could include and use.  It depends on what you want to do.  `npm` has many libraries that you can download and use with node.  I would recommend at least downloading and using **[underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/)** for declarative programming.  They are good to have.

There are many other cool libraries/fameworks you can try like **[sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!), [mean.io](http://mean.io/#!/), and [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)**.

Express is great though.  It really helps with structure and handling routes and middleware.  (For example, I was able to add gzip to my respsonses with one line of middleware code).  You could do it all without express, but it makes working with node.js so much easier.

If you want to use Web Sockets, use **[Socket.io](http://socket.io/)**.  Web Sockets are great for real-time information.  The example given is always chat, but you could use it like stack overflow when a new message, or new rep comes in.  Basically something happened from another user and you want to display it without a page refresh or polling.

To handle larger volume on an "Enterprise" level, look at the **[Node Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)** functionality.  You can create a node process per CPU processor core.

Again, it would be good for you to describe more about what you are trying to do, but you could build a web app with just node.js and express.

Comment: I am just trying to understand node and its related frameworks in general . Mainly trying to understand if node is suitable for enterprise applications with a large number of concurrent users ? If so what framework is best with ease of use , support for web sockets ?

Comment: Please see the answer again to answer these questions.  Node is really fun and definitely ready for enterprise.